# How to instantiate a Java generic inner class in Scala?

Tags: java, scala

```
// Parent.java
public class Parent {

    public class Tuple3<X, Y, Z> {
        public final X x;
        public final Y y;
        public final Z z;
        public Tuple3(X x, Y y, Z z) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.z = z;
        }
        public X _1() {
            return x;
        }
        public Y _2() {
            return y;
        }
        public Z _3() {
            return z;
        }
    }
    ....
}
```

Then if I want to instantiate a `Tuple3<String,String,Boolean>` object in scala how do I write?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially the same way you'd do it in Java.

```
val outer = new Parent
val inner = new outer.Tuple3("hi", "there", true)
```